# load data to wpf tree view using observable collection

Tags: wpf, wcf

My Wcf service has two data contracts called **Apps** and **SubApps**.Also I have two methods in server side called `List<string> GetAppIds()` and `List<string> GetSubAppIds(string AppId)`.

I want to load those AppIds and SubAppId into the treeview control  in wpf client. when i add delete apps and subaps modifications should apply to the treeview. Would you give me a solution to this one?

Treeview structure should be like below:

```
App1
 |_SubApp 1
 |_SubApp 2
App2
 |_SubApp 1
 |_SubApp 2
```

Comment: Your question is pretty broad, please specify what you already have and what is not done

Comment: Some thoughts which might help you:

1. WCF contract should not contains `ObservableCollection` type since it is UI layer instrument which provides automatic binding notifications
2. WCF contract should defineas simpler as you can stick with collection types like `IEnumerable<T>`, `IList<T>`
3. On  applciation side just convert received list to `ObservableCollection` and that's it